# PayPal : Authorize once, capture in multiple parts

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I know that PayPal supports generic authorization/capture and I know that they support capturing an amount less than the authorized amount. But is there some way to capture multiple, separate small amounts that add up to the authorized amount?

My use case roughly as follows: Orders can have multiple items. They may not ship at the same time. We would like to defer the billing for each item until it ships so that people can cancel the item before then and we don't have to pay processing fees on the refund. We don't want to have to do separate orders with separate authorizations because that would be really annoying for the user. We just want to have a cart that is authorized at one time from the user's side and captured per-item from our side.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Payments v2 API, there is a `final_capture` parameter to indicate whether there will be more captures, or not.

See the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_capture